# Unwanted automatically adding timestamp on DATE in SQL with express API call

Tags: sql, api, express

I have a frontend in Vanilla JS, a backend in Express and a MYSQL running on a Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

I created a database with the CLI.

```
CREATE DATABASE tryout;
```

After that I created a table inside the tryout database. Then I added some data in it.

```
USE tryout;
CREATE TABLE myDates (dateEvent DATE);
INSERT INTO myDates (dateEvent) VALUES ('2022-01-01');
```

When I do a

```
SELECT * FROM myDates;
```

I get the result you should expect => 2022-01-01.

However. I have a backend in Express with this piece of code:

```
    app.get('/myDates', function(req, res) {
    dbConn.query('SELECT * from myDates', function(error, results, fields) {
        if (error) throw error;
        
        return res.send({error: false, data: results})
    })
})
```

The backend works fine, but when I use Postman (or my frontend for that matter) and I make a GET request to localhost:3000/myDates, I get a JSON back like this:

```
{
"error": false,
"data": [
    {
        "dateEvent": "2021-12-31T23:00:00.000Z"
    }
  ]}
```

Somehow it added a timestamp - 1 hour. Resulting in the wrong date.

If I make another table with a DATETIME as datatype instead of DATE and add a value of 2022-01-01 01:00:00. I get a JSON back with a dateEvent value of "2022-01-01 00:00:00". That's a workaround, but I'd rather have it not to act like that :) It happens to every date (not only 2022-01-01) I just made that a easy reference.

Can someone explain to me why this is happening? My quess was that there was something wrong on my timezone settings on my machine, but if so, I still wouldn't understand why there is a timestamp added in a SQL with a column with a DATE datatype and not a DATETIME datatype.

Comment: Try explicit timezone in the query `SELECT  cast(dateEvent as datetime)  at time zone 'UTC' from myDates`

Comment: This syntax wasn't working for me (could it be it is SQL server syntax? Just asking, eager to learn here.). However it got me rethink my process (I'm in Europe and my timezone is CET). After some research I found I could use CONVERT_TZ(). But I needed to populate the timezone table in MYSQL. After a restart I could use this statement to make it work:
select date_format(convert_tz(dateEvent, 'UCT', 'CET'), '%Y-%m-%d') as date from myDates.